# Modify column data stored as JSON

Tags: json, mariadb, mysql-json

Lets say i have json column as JSON_COLUMN in which i am storing the data in below format

**Table structure: (2 columns only)**

```
ID - Autoincrement

JSON_COLUMN - Varchar2(1000)
```

**Sample Data**:

```
ID : 1

JSON_COLUMN :

[
   {
      "Name":"Number",
      "Id":"PhoneNumber",
      "Value":"+393123456789"
   },
   {
      "Name":"Name",
      "Id":"FirstName",
      "Value":"John"
   },
   {
      "Name":"City",
      "Id":"CityID",
      "Value":"NYC"
   }
]
```

Now i want update query of mariadb which should replace value of City from NYC to CALI

update tablename set JSON_COLUMN = **????** **Not sure what to keep here** where id = 1;

Comment: Why are you storing data in JSON when it looks like it's just an array of similar objects? It should be a second table, where the array items are rows, and the object fields are columns. Then it's very easy to update the data in the way you describe.

Comment: Also, please be specific about which database you use, MySQL or MariaDB? These are different, incompatible products, especially with respect to their JSON implementation.

Comment: JSON_SET is the keyword you are looking for when working with arrays in sql db. PlanetScale just posted a really interesting video about this yesterday https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cDzrY-QW4Ck

Comment: MariaDB  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_set/

MySql https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-set

Comment: "JSON" is not meant to be a basic RDBMS container like "table".  Consider storing that datum in the table as its own column -- where straightforward SQL can search for it, update it, etc.

Answer (score 1):

mysql and mariadb haven't the datatype varchar2 but oracle has.

Using a simple `REPLACE` can help you.

IF the term NYC is only one in your json, this is enough

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (ID  int  Auto_increment primary key,

JSON_COLUMN  Varchar(1000))
```

```
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (NULL,'[
   {
      "Name":"Number",
      "Id":"PhoneNumber",
      "Value":"+393123456789"
   },
   {
      "Name":"Name",
      "Id":"FirstName",
      "Value":"John"
   },
   {
      "Name":"City",
      "Id":"CityID",
      "Value":"NYC"
   }
]')
```

```
UPDATE mytable SET JSON_COLUMN = REPLACE(JSON_COLUMN,'NYC','CALI') WHERE ID = 1
```

> ```
> Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
```

| ID | JSON_COLUMN |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [ { "Name":"Number", "Id":"PhoneNumber", "Value":"+393123456789" }, { "Name":"Name", "Id":"FirstName", "Value":"John" }, { "Name":"City", "Id":"CityID", "Value":"CALI" } ] |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lenXza6G)

If you know the index you can use JSON_REPLACE

```
UPDATE mytable 
  SET JSON_COLUMN = JSON_REPLACE(JSON_COLUMN,'$[2].Value','CALI') WHERE ID = 1
```

> ```
> Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_COLUMN,'$[2].Value') FROM mytable
```

| JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_COLUMN,'$[2].Value') |
| --- |
| "CALI" |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AAzz4Amd)

Comment: Wouldn't this do the wrong thing if "NYC" appears in another part of the JSON document?

Comment: @BillKarwin i clarified it, every user has only one cityid, so it should be unique in the json

Comment: Thanks a lot its working as expected. But i agree to Bill Karwin. How to handle such scenarios?

Comment: json is a good format to save data, but to edit specific parts it get fast ver messy, so you should get the json and use anaother language to parse the json and update it

Comment: @user1251973  i added a version, but you need to now the index in the array

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that updates only the 'NYC' corresponding to the key 'Value' in an array.

```
with cte as (
  select ID, j.* from tablename
  cross join json_table(JSON_COLUMN, '$[*]' columns(
    ord for ordinality, 
    Value varchar(100) path '$.Value')
  ) as j 
  where j.Value = 'NYC'
) 
update tablename cross join cte
set tablename.json_column = json_set(json_column, concat('$[', cte.ord-1, '].Value'), 'CALI')
where cte.id = tablename.id;
```

This works in MySQL 8.0 or later, but not in MariaDB, because MariaDB doesn't support a common table expression before `update`.

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/tN9Q9-Od

---

Here's a solution for MariaDB 10.6 or later (won't work with older versions):

```
update tablename
cross join (
  select ID, j.* from tablename
  cross join json_table(JSON_COLUMN, '$[*]' columns(
    ord for ordinality,
    Value varchar(100) path '$.Value')
  ) as j
  where j.Value = 'NYC'
) as t
set tablename.json_column = json_set(json_column, concat('$[', t.ord-1, '].Value'), 'CALI');
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/fKHp8BmZ

Comment: I need for mariadb